# Jenkinsfile error: Unable to resolve class Workbook

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

When I build my Jenkins job, I receive the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 198: unable to resolve class Workbook 
 @ line 198, column 42.
                        Workbook xssfWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(file) 
1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:981)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:626)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:575)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:677)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:689)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:513)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:335)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Finished: FAILURE
```

This is how I've imported and how the code is written (ignore the indenting, was messed up during copy paste):

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*

...

stage("Load Box") {
                script {
                    dir('box') {
                        def first_cell = []

                        def actObj = new ActiveXObject('Excel.Application')
                        def actWorkBooks = actObj.WorkBooks.Open("path")
                        def sheet = actWorkBooks.Sheets('path')

                        FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File("path"))
                        Workbook xssfWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile)
                        XSSFSheet workSheet = xssfWorkBook.getSheet('sheetPath')

                        for (Row r : workSheet) {
                            Cell c = r.getCell(1)
                            if (c != null) {
                                if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                                    first_cell.add(1)
                                }
                            }
                        }                           
                    }
                }
            }
```

Is there something wrong with the way I declared it?
Are there other resources I could look for to help me solve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Please show your Jenkinsfile.  FYI, even Jenkinsfile use Groovy as coding language, but the Jenkins use self Groovy compiler which Only support limited Groovy.

Comment: @yong I've attached the relevant parts to the Jenkinsfile

Comment: you can import Groovy build-in class in Jenkins pipeline, but Apache POI is not Groovy build-in.  Even more,  Jenkins maybe not support all build-in of standard Groovy.   If you can contact your Jenkins admin, you can work with him to see Jenkins System configuration allow you to config global classpath for Jenkins Groovy compiler or not, then you can add Apache POI jar to global classpath.